Spring Application context logs are not printed in Spring WebApplicationInitializer was project in RHEL 8
Spring Application and other java logs are not printed in Spring WebApplicationInitializer WAR project in RHEL 8.
I'm using default logging.properties config. This is happening after upgrading log4j2 jar from 2.17.0 to 2.17.2.
I have reviewed with tomcat documentation also.
